# Can pins on a Google Map link to other websites?

Tags: google-maps

I'd like to set up a Google Map or any other map with pins in certain locations and have those pins link to other websites.

Anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var MyPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(18, 78);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: MyPlace,
        url: 'http://www.wikipedia.org/',
        title: 'This link opens Wikipedia home page',
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.location.href = marker.url;
    });

  </script>
```